# SVN Equivalent of CVS -kv Keyword Option

Tags: svn, migration, cvs

In CVS, I could checkout files with the a `cvs checkout -kv` which would replace keywords with their expanded values.   For example, what would otherwise be `$Id: 1.23$` is simply `1.23` in the checked out version when using `-kv`.

In one very specific use case, I found this handy.

Since migrating our repositories to SVN, I haven't been able to find an equivalent.

Is there one?

I'm aware of the `svn propset svn:keywords "Id" file.txt` command required to enable the keywords, but this is about replacing the name + value of the keyword with just the value.

Comment: I don't see a way to do this with SVN. Out of curiosity, what's your use case? I imagine this isn't provided because it would be too easy to forget that you'd blown away all of the keywords in your working copy and to overwrite them in your next commit with just the values.

Comment: Managing text files which sent to server as out-of-code configuration.   Intended use: check out / export latest files from SVN, push to server manually or through utility, delete SVN files.  An information service displays the Revision # on request (dumping subsections of file) to allow validation that correct configuration version loaded.  In that case, no semantic difference between `$Revision: 6483$` and `6483`, just a preference, if it was simple to do.  I could manipulate the files or massage info service output, but not worth the effort in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported as of Subversion 1.8. I guess that you might want to report this as a feature request to Subversion community. I suggest trying users@ Subversion mailing list first.

"Apache Subversion Mailing Lists": http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html.